# UEFI: BIOS boot windows on the HDD if i try to boot UEFI ubuntu 12.10 from USB, why?

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot, uefi

I started by using the USB install creator form my 12.10 installation, with the 12.10 image.

on my bios i disable safe boot, and enable legacy mode (or CSM a my bios calls it).

I reboot and press the key that the BIOS demands to select boot device.

in the list I have:

- P0: Windows boot manager
- UEFI: USB my_pen_drive_brand
- USB: my_pen_drive_brand

If I select "UEFI: usb" it will flash the screen, and go back to the same menu... if i select it again, it will flash the screen and boot windows.

If I select "USB" i boot into the legacy mode for the installer just fine and everything works. But i'm following the [UEFI guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_HDD_in_EFI_mode) and since I want to dual boot with windows8, if I understood the guide correctly, i Must install in UEFI mode.

So, i can select this "USB" and get:

[image]

but the guide says i must select "UEFI: USB" and get this:

[image]

Or am I messing things up? Does the fact that windows8 can boot from P0 (when safeboot is enabled it shows "UEFI: P0" or something) means i can install ubuntu in legacy mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disregard that, I've downloaded the 32bit image by mistake.

Will not delete the question as it may help somebody.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer to explain why the 64-bit version is necessary in this situation. Then this question and answer will be clearly helpful to others in similar situations.

Comment: i have no idea :) i Do know that UEFI firmware and it's tools that run on the OS must be of the same architecture (hence a 64bit firmware can't be talked to using 32bit OS tools), but why the firmware and tools are only included in ubuntu 64 is beyond me. it's just a fact for now, if you want UEFI support in ubuntu, you must use the 64bit version. more: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting_an_OS_using_UEFI